# What to use for HTTP requests in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I need to do HTTP request in controller Laravel for getting data by URL.
The remote URL returns JSON data format.
What to use for HTTP requests in Laravel except standart  PHP Curl?

Comment: https://github.com/guzzle/guzzle

Comment: you mean like getting some posted values from URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Guzzle](http://guzzlephp.org/) is a popular cross-framework for making HTTP calls to external services. Laravel already has this included as a dependency for its mail integration services (Sparkpost, Mailgun, Mandrill).

Edit `composer.json` and in the `require` section add `"guzzlehttp/guzzle": "~6"` after the laravel/framework line.

`composer update`

At the top of your controller add `use GuzzleHttp\Client`;

Then within a method you can use it like this:

```
$client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
$res = $client->request('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user', [
    'auth' => ['user', 'pass']
]);
echo $res->getStatusCode();
// 200
echo $res->getHeaderLine('content-type');
// 'application/json; charset=utf8'
echo $res->getBody();
// {"type":"User"...'
```

There is also a [a Laracast on using Guzzle with Laravel](https://laracasts.com/lessons/http-requests-with-guzzle).

Comment: PHP can not see: `$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client();`

Comment: Tested this out and updated answer to include composer.json. Also added a slash to the start of the instantiation line.